# Pure JavaScript Image Grab-Zoom?

Tags: javascript, html, image, zooming

In the past I came across http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/ which was a great find and very simple to use for a variety of images. I am looking for a grab-zoom feature using pure-javascript rather than jQuery. Is there any Pure-Javascript solution for this? I've attempted this with no luck so far:

Javascript:

```
    var imgSize = 1;
function zoomIn() {
imgSize += 0.1;
document.body.style.imgSize = imgSize + "em";
}
function zoomOut() {
    imgSize -= 0.1;
    document.body.style.imgSize = imgSize + "em";
}
```

HTML

```
<img src="picture.png" value="+" onClick="zoomIn()"/>
```

Thanks in advance for any helpful tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to display the smaller sized image ("original") and when the mouse is hovering over the container, the background image of the container is revealed. The background image is large, and the CSS background is clipped by the container's size. Mouse events are tracked. You'll have to work out the measurement and math yourself.

```
<div id="imageview" style="position:relative;width:300px;height:200px;"
>
  <img src="300x200.jpg" id="original" onmouseover="this.style.display='none';">

</div>

<script>

  document.getElementById('imageview').onmouseover=function(e){
    document.getElementById('original').style.display='none';
    var x,y;
    if (e) {x=e.clientX;y=e.clientY;} else {x=event.clientX; y=event.clientY;}

    document.getElementById('imageview').orgx=x;
    document.getElementById('imageview').orgy=y;

  }

  document.getElementById('imageview').onmousemove=function(e){
    var x,y;
    if (e) {x=e.clientX;y=e.clientY;} else {x=event.clientX; y=event.clientY;}

    var orgx=document.getElementById('imageview').orgx;
    var orgy=document.getElementById('imageview').orgy;

    //now you have x, y, orgx, and org y, so you can do some math
    // ...

    var posx, posy;

    document.getElementById('imageview').backgroundImage='url(600x400.jpg)';
    document.getElementById('imageview').backgroundPosition=-1*posx+'px '+ -1*posy+'px';


  }

</script>
```

Comment: This comment is fine however I was looking for clickable solution if possible. As in you click the original image and it will "zoom" if you click the "zoomed" image it will show the original again. Thank you so much for the advice though I'm gonna try to work with your code and go from there.

Comment: can you put it in the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Please give this image zooming library (written by me) a try: https://github.com/kingdido999/zooming

It's implemented in pure JavaScript with no extra dependency.

Comment: You should always disclose your affiliation in your answers when promoting a library of yours.

Comment: Edited my comment. Thanks for the advice.